# Checkbox status jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have this HTML and I have to check wich one of theese checboxes is checked and get the value of the selected checbox to add it to an array.
I've tried different code but I don't know where is the problem

```
<div class="row ">   
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-centered ">
        <input type="checkbox" id="piega1" class="servizioSection2" name="imgSection2"value="PiegaByWellaProfessionals">
        <label class="piega" for="piega1">
            <img src="img/piega1.png" for="piega1" alt="" class="img-responsive immaginePiega ">
        </label>
        <h1 class="immagineTitoloPiega">PIEGA BY WELLA PROFESSIONALS</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5  col-centered piege">
        <input type="checkbox" id="piega2" name="imgSection2" class="piege servizioSection2" value="PiegaBySystemProfessionals">
        <label for="piega2" class="piega ">
            <img src="img/piega2.png" for="piega2" alt="" class="img-responsive immaginePiega">
        </label>
        <h1 class="immagineTitoloPiega">PIEGA BY SYSTEM PROFESSIONALS</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the Jquery to check the checbox status. I also don't know why if I click on a checbox i get the value of all of them and not just the one I clicked

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
   var serviziSection2 = $('#serviziSection2Def');
   $('input:checkbox').on('click', function(){
     var servizi = [];
     $('.servizioSection2:checkbox').each(function(){
       var checkbox = $(this).val();
             console.log(checkbox)
       if($(checkbox).is(':checked') == true){
           servizi.push(checkbox.next('label').html());
           console.log(servizi)
       }
     });
     serviziSection2.html(servizi.join(', '));
   });
});
```

Comment: [you're way overthinking this and doing way to much **work**](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: `var arr = $('input').serializeArray()` And if you just need the values `var arr = $('input').serializeArray().map(function(v,k) { return v.value })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're assigning a new click event to all checkbox's every time anything in the `document` is clicked on. Secondly, jQuery already comes with some simple built in features for this. Take a look at [**`.serializeArray()`**](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

What you're trying to achieve is as simple as:

```js
//  this is typical starter for a block of jQuery code.
//  this is same as document.ready = function() { ...
$(function() {
  //  this sets events on ALL elements matching selector, 
  //  including dynamically created ones (inserted by JavaScript code)
  $(document)  //  as you can see, i'm assigning a 'change' event to 'input[type=checkbox]'s
    .on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(e) {
      //  first i set a variable containing an array of Name/Value Objects of all CHECKED checkboxes
      //  this will NOT grab values of any unchecked box
      var checked = $('input').serializeArray(),
          //  this next variable simply creates an array of ONLY the values from our previous array.
          values = checked.map(function(val, key) { return val.value });
      
      //  display values as a single string of text
      $('fieldset pre').text(values.join(', '));
      
      //  and if you still want that HTML part
      //  this first variable gets all labels that only follow CHECKED inputs
      var $checkedInputs = $('input:checked + label'),
          //  creating simple placeholder element variable to get all the HTML onto
          newHTML = $('<div/>');
      //  add each needed piece of HTML to our placeholder
      $checkedInputs.each(function(index) { newHTML.append($(this).html()); });
      //  display output of our new HTML
      //  newHTML.html() will output ONLY the html we put into it, and NOT the outer div created for this variable
      $('fieldset p').html(newHTML.html());
    });
})
```

```css
img { height: 50px; }
h1 { display: inline-block; font-size: 1.25em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">   
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-centered ">
        <input type="checkbox" id="piega1" class="servizioSection2" name="imgSection2"value="PiegaByWellaProfessionals">
        <label class="piega" for="piega1">
            <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" for="piega1" alt="" class="img-responsive immaginePiega ">
        </label>
        <h1 class="immagineTitoloPiega">PIEGA BY WELLA PROFESSIONALS</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5  col-centered piege">
        <input type="checkbox" id="piega2" name="imgSection2" class="piege servizioSection2" value="PiegaBySystemProfessionals">
        <label for="piega2" class="piega ">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png" for="piega2" alt="" class="img-responsive immaginePiega">
        </label>
        <h1 class="immagineTitoloPiega">PIEGA BY SYSTEM PROFESSIONALS</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Output</legend>
  <h3>values</h3>
  <pre></pre>
  <hr />
  <h3>HTML</h3>
  <p></p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox has no value.
You set `var checkbox = $(this).val()`
and then check if `$(checkbox).is(':checked')`
Just use `$(this).is(':checked')`

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind to `change` events on the checkbox rather than on `click` events on the whole document. I.e this section does not make any sense:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
   $('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
     ... 
   });
});
```

Literally it binds a new click handler on all checkboxes whenever you click anywhere in the document.

Here's a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var output = $('#serviziSection2Def');
  $('.servizioSection2:checkbox').change(function() {
    output.text($('.servizioSection2:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(', '));
  })
});
```

```css
h1 { font-size: 16px; } /* just for readability on SO, ignore */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">   
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-centered ">
        <input type="checkbox" id="piega1" class="servizioSection2" name="imgSection2"value="PiegaByWellaProfessionals">
        <label class="piega" for="piega1">
            <img src="img/piega1.png" for="piega1" alt="" class="img-responsive immaginePiega ">
        </label>
        <h1 class="immagineTitoloPiega">PIEGA BY WELLA PROFESSIONALS</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5  col-centered piege">
        <input type="checkbox" id="piega2" name="imgSection2" class="piege servizioSection2" value="PiegaBySystemProfessionals">
        <label for="piega2" class="piega ">
            <img src="img/piega2.png" for="piega2" alt="" class="img-responsive immaginePiega">
        </label>
        <h1 class="immagineTitoloPiega">PIEGA BY SYSTEM PROFESSIONALS</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="serviziSection2Def">
</div>
```

Note on the side: Never ever use `element.html(...)` with unsanitized user input, since this can break your website layout. Use `element.text(...)` whenever possible, this escapes entered HTML.